# Error loading gnome ubuntu session

Tags: gnome, xorg, gnome-session

After restart ubuntu i get this after login :

```
: unable to launch "gnome-session --session=ubuntu" X session ---
"gnome-session --session=ubuntu" not found; falling back to default session.
```

Same thing find it in **.xsession-errors**

Gnome start in default mode.

Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got same error on 13.04 x64

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command, then log out and log back in.

```
echo "gnome-session --session=gnome-classic" > ~/.xsession
```

Comment: This don't help.